# Viewing certificates in certificate chain conveniently in MacOS from finder

Tags: finder, certificate

In the MacOS finder, there is a convenient viewer for certificates, with the "icon" view
[image: icon view option]. If the file contains a single certificate, it formats and displays the certificate very nicely, e.g., as below.
[image]

However, if the file contains a certificate chain (multiple certificates one after another), then only the first one shows, and the finder is silent on the existence of additional certificates in the file. Is there any option or way to get it to show all the certificates? Or is the "manual" way (split into multiple files, each with one of the certs from the certificate chain, then view each one by one) the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in macOS 11 and earlier, there is no built-in way for the Finder's Quick View to show multiple certificates contained in a single file.

Comment: Up to and including MacOS 11 Big Sur? So is there a way in Big Sur? I tested on Catalina

Comment: There are currently no versions of macOS that show multiple certificates in a single file within the Quick View feature of the Finder.